# Panels page 'Taxonomy term template' localized term doesn't translate

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, panels, i18n-l10n

When enabling the Taxonomy term template on a vocabulary that has been set to 'Localize', I translate the term, but then viewing the term only displays in the original language. Switching language has no affect on the description and the title of the term.